# Qu'est-ce qu'une fausse régression?

Tags: orthographe

Sur la page Wiktionnaire du mot "doigt", il est indiqué que son orthographe est une *[fausse régression](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doigt#%C3%89tymologie)* du latin classique *digitus*.

En quoi cette régression de l'orthographe "doi" en ancien français est-elle fausse?
Par exemple aucune mention similaire n'apparait sur la page de "misanthrope" que Molière écrivait "misantrope".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après l'étymologie du mot au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doigt)  a été faite une réfection étymologique du mot « doi » qui a consisté à ajouter « gt »; mais comme « doi », étant issue du pluriel neutre de « digitus », c'est à dire « ditus », ne venait pas d'un mot ayant « gt » parmi ses lettres, le « retour en arrière » (régression) n'est pas exact.

> 3. 1174-80 (Ch. de Troyes, Perceval, éd. F. Lecoy, 8796 : le plus petit doi de mon pié). Du lat. class. digitus, *ditus « doigt de la main, du pied », forme doigt par réfection étymol.; l'a. fr. deie, doie plur. de genre indéterminé (1 a) est issu du plur. neutre *dita à valeur collective.